# Accuracy is increasing so fast ? converging to 99?

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function

I have as input the features embeddings of two drugs, and the task is a to classify whether there is an interaction btw those two drugs or not. The problem is that accuracy is increasing so fast and converging to 1, so do loss is decreasing so fast...

So, please if you have an idea about what s causing that , i will be grateful !

Here is my code!

def DNN_ATT():

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(400))
droprate=0.5

attention_probs = Dense(400,activation='relu',use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros', name='attention1')(input_layer)

att = Dense(400,activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='random_uniform', name='attention')(attention_probs)

train_in = Dense(32, activation='relu', name="FullyConnectLayer7")(att)
train_in = BatchNormalization()(train_in)
train_in = Dropout(droprate)(train_in)

out=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(train_in)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=out)

return model
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK63Z.png)

```
 # Define per-fold score containers
acc_per_fold = []
loss_per_fold = []

fold_no = 1
for a, b in kfold.split(X_train,y_train):


  # Split the training data into training and validation sets
  input_train_fold, input_val_fold, target_train_fold, target_val_fold = train_test_split(train[a], Y[a], test_size=0.1)
  # Define the model architecture
  model = DNN_ATT()


  # Compile the model
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.00001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
   # Generate a print
  print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
  print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')

  # Fit data to model
  history = model.fit(input_train_fold, target_train_fold,
              batch_size=32,
              epochs=50,
              validation_data=(input_val_fold, target_val_fold))
  

  # Generate generalization metrics
  scores = model.evaluate(train[b], Y[b], verbose=0)
  print(f'Score for fold {fold_no}: {model.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model.metrics_names[1]} of {scores[1]*100}%')
  acc_per_fold.append(scores[1] * 100)
  loss_per_fold.append(scores[0])

  # Increase fold number
  fold_no = fold_no + 1
  # == Provide average scores ==
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Score per fold')
for i in range(0, len(acc_per_fold)):
  print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
  print(f'> Fold {i+1} - Loss: {loss_per_fold[i]} - Accuracy: {acc_per_fold[i]}%')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Average scores for all folds:')
print(f'> Accuracy: {np.mean(acc_per_fold)} (+- {np.std(acc_per_fold)})')
print(f'> Loss: {np.mean(loss_per_fold)}')
print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```